# Python module not found even after installing using pip

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have a Docker image which has some Python libraries installed with command `pip install packaganame`. But when I use that image to run some automation, it gives `ModuleNotFoundError`. When I build that Docker image again with package install commands as `python -m pip install packagaename`, then it is working fine.

Why just `pip install package name` doesn't work? What can I do to make this command also work?

Comment: Show us the Dockerfile.

Comment: `python` and `pip` may be coming from different Python installations (e.g., Python 2 vs Python 3, or system interpreter vs local venv). We'd need to see your Dockerfile to know

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

The typical issue is creating file:

```
requirements.txt
```

Puttin there every dependencies, then (by adding those 2 lines)
Copying that file - and running with upgrade:

```
COPY ./requirements.txt /voicesense/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /projectName/requirements.txt
```

---

There is another story, when you're using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) for managing packages.

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant to the question. The OP's question is why `python -m pip install` works but `pip install` does not work.

Comment: I'm also not sure, OP not provide necessary details, hope that answer may support in finding solution.